# Trying to print an array argument error

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Im trying to print out the contents of an array and I'm running into an issue when looping through the array to print the elements. The error it is giving me is:

The method ImportTeams() in the type FileRead is not applicable for the arguments (int)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileRead {

     public String[] ImportTeams(){

        String[] Teams; 
        BufferedReader br = null; 
        int linecount = 0;  

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath")); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            while (br.readLine() != null){
                linecount ++;
            }
            br.close();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
            if (linecount % 2 != 0) {
                linecount ++;
            }
            Teams = new String[linecount];
            String teamcounter;
            int arraycount = 0;
            while ((teamcounter = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Teams[arraycount] = teamcounter;
                arraycount++; 
                }
            return Teams;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;        
    }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            FileRead fr = new FileRead();
            for(int i =0; i <fr.ImportTeams().length; i++){
                System.out.println(fr.ImportTeams(i));
            }




        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(fr.ImportTeams(i));
```

should be :

```
  System.out.println(fr.ImportTeams()[i]);
```

When you access elements from `array`, you need to use `array[index]` syntax.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was going to be something small alright. Thanks a lot! It won't let me accept the answer for another 12 mins, but I'll be sure to do it

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(fr.ImportTeams(i));
```

Your method ImportTeams doesn's have any parameter.

use

```
System.out.println(fr.ImportTeams()[i]);
```